# How to set type of React Functional Component property to Styled Component `styled.div`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

interface ChildProps {
  color: string
}

const Child = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props: ChildProps) => props.color};
`

interface ParentProps {
  node: FunctionComponent<ChildProps> // How to set node type to Styled Component `styled.div`?
}

const Parent = function(props: ParentProps) {
  const Node = props.node
  return <Node color="white" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install -D @types/styled-components
```

```js
import styled, { StyledComponent } from "styled-components";

interface ParentProps {
  node: StyledComponent<"div", any, ChildProps, never> 
}
```

You can btw look up the type of something e.g. by hovering over it in VSCode.

---

Tip: Use a generic to declare the styled-component's props, instead of declaring it in the function. And in this case you can destructure the `color`.

```js
const Child = styled.div<ChildProps>`
  background-color: ${({ color }) => color};
`
```

Comment: Thanks Eyk! Do you know if there is a way to use a generic type? Ideally, I would like to avoid depending on `styled-components` and allow users to set the `node` property to any Functional Component that returns a div extended with `ChildProps` types.